# Commentary on the chess game in Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows?

Tags: sherlock-holmes-a-game-of-shadows

I've just [rewatched the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LqfrY87U-0) from *Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows* (2011) where Holmes and Moriarty play a game of literal chess while also discussing the metaphorical game they've been playing with each other. Holmes wins both, but I've seen a number of interesting claims made in the comments of the above-linked Youtube video:

- > The chess game here is based on an actual match - Bent Larsen vs Tigran Petrosian in 1966 in Santa Monica. And that match is now known as the Game of Shadows!
- > That analogy [Queen sacrifice] was for Irene Adler who was [sacrificed] early into the game.. it was her death that led Holmes to discover incriminating evidence against the Prof and with it, an avenue to shut down his shop. The mating sequence ends with a seemingly passive rook on the a file - the most inept officer in the history of Scotland Yard - Lestrade.

The video linked in the answer to [this related question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/87788/27759) also claims that, indeed, the game is similar (not identical) to the real-life Larsen versus Petrosian match, and shows Holmes's queen sacrifice and mate with rook. My question is: **is there any commentary from the makers of the film about how deliberate all this was?** Is there any particular significance to the Larsen versus Petrosian match: e.g. was it chosen because it was the most significant historical chess game featuring a successful queen sacrifice and mate with rook, or was it really called "the Game of Shadows" thereby giving the film its name? Has anyone confirmed that the queen sacrifice and passive rook mate symbolically represent Irene Adler and Inspector Lestrade?

Comment: I'm so excited that you even watched that movie!!  ;)